# segmentation fault when declaring a table as double *table in a structure

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I want to declare a table as a variable in a structre:

```cpp
 struct func_params{
        double *table;
     };
```

When calling the table in my main programm

```cpp
   int main(int argc, char **argv){

            struct func_params params;
            printf("%e \n",params.table[0]);
      return(0);
 
      }
```

I am getting a `segmentation fault` error, but if I define my table as `double table[2500]` then it's fine. I am wondering why since I thought that tables in C where basically pointers...

Answer (score 2):

You must initialize (allocate buffer and assign that) the pointer before dereferencing that.

In general, values of uninitialized non-static local variables (having automatic duration) are indeterminate and using such values invokes *undefined behavipr*. therefore, it is not find even with definition like `double table[2500]` if it is printed without initialization.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct func_params{
  double *table;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  struct func_params params;

  params.table = malloc(sizeof(*params.table) * 2500); /* initialize pointer (allocate) */
  if (params.table == NULL) return 1; /* check if allocation succeeded */

  params.table[0] = 42; /* initialize the element to print */

  printf("%e \n",params.table[0]);

  free(params.table); /* deallocate the buffer */
  return(0);

}
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! If I understand correctly, ```*params.table``` refers to the first value of the table?

Comment: Yes. `A[B]` is equivalent to `*((A)+(B))`. `*params.table` is equivalent to `*(params.table+0)`, which is equivalent to `params.table[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 *params.table // first element.
```

To access the next element

```
 *(params.table + 1) // next element
```

The name of an array is the address of the array. And logically
the address of the array and the address of the first element are the same.
The allocated memory allows you to use the pointer like an array.

```
 array == &array[0] // name of array, same address as 1st array element
 *(array) == array[0] //value 1st element
 *(array + 1) == array[1] // value 2nd element
```